# How to find out a column with carriage return in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner in SQL and trying to run a query like this:

```
select id from "a_table" where col_value = 'ABCDEF';
```

Now in the table `a_table`, `col_value` has both

```
'ABCDEF'
```

and

```
'ABCD
EF'
```

(with a carriage return)

My question is how can I construct my query so that if I search for `'ABCDEF'` in the table where **ABCDEF** is present and may or may not have a carriage return in it.

Comment: where col_value **LIKE** 'ABCD%';

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is I do not know where exactly the carriage return is.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `replace` function

```
select id
from "a_table"
where replace(replace(col_value, '\r', ''), '\n', '') = 'ABCDEF'
```

And if you need you can update `bad` rows

```
update "a_table"
set
  col_value = replace(replace(col_value, '\r', ''), '\n', '')
where col_value <> replace(replace(col_value, '\r', ''), '\n', '')
```

But before update it's desirable to check them using the following query

```
select
  id,
  col_value,
  replace(replace(col_value, '\r', ''), '\n', '') new_value
from "a_table"
where col_value <> replace(replace(col_value, '\r', ''), '\n', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

This can solve your issue

```
select id from "a_table" where replace(col_value,'\n','') = 'ABCDEF';
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve data without carriage return please try

```
    select id from "a_table" where col_value = 'ABCDEF' and col_value NOT REGEXP "\r\n";
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, using replace function solved the issue. As Leran2002 pointed out updating the table is the next task.